# How to induce maximum matching and minimum vertex cover from each other in a bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory

1. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithm), in a bipartite graph, when given a maximum
   matching, there is way to construct a vertex cover of the same size
   as the matching:

   > Consider a bipartite graph where the vertices are partitioned into
   >   left (L) and right (R) sets. Suppose there is a maximum matching which
   >   partitions the edges into those used in the matching ($E_m$) and those
   >   not ($E_0$). **Let T consist of all unmatched vertices from L, as well
   >   as all vertices reachable from those by going left-to-right along
   >   edges from $E_0$ and right-to-left along edges from $E_m$. This
   >   essentially means that for each unmatched vertex in L, we add into T
   >   all vertices that occur in a path alternating between edges from $E_0$
   >   and $E_m$.**
   >
   > Then $(L \setminus T) \cup (R \cap T)$ is a minimum vertex cover.
   >   Intuitively, vertices in T are added if they are in R and subtracted if they are in L to obtain the minimum vertex cover.
   >   Thus, the
   >   Hopcroft–Karp algorithm for finding maximum matchings in bipartite
   >   graphs may also be used to solve the vertex cover problem efficiently
   >   in these graphs.

   I  am not sure how $T$ is constructed, and cannot picture $T$ even after reading the sentences in bold. So I wonder how to understand those sentences?
2. Conversely, in a bipartite graph, when given a minimum vertex cover,
   what is some way to construct a matching of the same size as the
   vertex cover?

Thanks!

PS: This is from my comment on [Fixee's reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/226110/1281).